# Import Specification Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I keep getting an import error when trying to bring in a text file through VBA.  All other files are working fine.  It keeps saying the text file does not exist.  Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```
Const cstrFolderE = "\\Data\Business Objects\tblSCFLAGCHECKER.txt"

        If FSO.FileExists(cstrFolderE) Then
           DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "tblSCFLAGCHECKER", "tblSCFLAG_CHECKER", cstrFolderE, True
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't named my import spec correctly. All sorted now.